# Variable In Controller Then Function

Tags: php

For some reason my variable doesn't pass to my SMS function?

```
public function visitor_signin(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->first_name;
    $mobile = $request->mobile;

    SMS::send('text::invite', ['data' => $data], function($sms) {
        $sms->to($mobile);
    });
}
```

I get the error: Undefined variable: mobile

Answer (score 1):

The [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of variables in functions is the function body. There is no variable or parameter named `$mobile` in the anonymous function you pass as a callback to the method `SMS::send()`.

You can use the [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) language construct to make the anonymous function know about the `$mobile` variable (defined in a different scope):

```
public function visitor_signin(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->first_name;
    $mobile = $request->mobile;

    SMS::send(
        'text::invite',
        ['data' => $data],
        function($sms) use ($mobile) {
            $sms->to($mobile);
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the variable into your anonymous function like this:

```
public function visitor_signin(Request $request)
{

    $data = $request->first_name;
    $mobile = $request->mobile;

    SMS::send('text::invite', ['data' => $data], function($sms) use($mobile) {
        $sms->to($mobile);
    });

}
```